# set Ubuntu to use english us or ca locale?

Tags: 17.04

I set my ubuntu to the russian language and deleted all other language packs. Now I can't read anything at all. I am trying to go back to English but unable to figure out how. Does anyone  know what I have to do to put my system back in english?

Comment: I decided to download and install this program: https://github.com/gaining/resetter to reset the locale to english. Worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know how what the enlish langugage packs packages names were called. I could not find the English language in "Language Support" app so I decided to download and install this program: https://github.com/gaining/resetter to reset the locale to english.

I used to custom reset option to install the missing English language packs and it worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings -> Language Support (blue flag). This should open the Language Support window. Click on Install / Remove Languages.

[Language Support Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLJDi.png)

In the Installed Languages window, scroll to English and check the box under the column labeled Installed. Then click Apply.

[Installed Languages Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM9Nt.png)

You should now be able to drag languages to arrange them in order of preference. You can also go back to the Install / Remove Languages and remove Russian if you no longer want it.

Comment: unfortunately english is not in the list